# Serve single live .TS for AVPlayer iOS

Tags: ios, video-streaming, avfoundation, avplayer, http-live-streaming

Given I have a live .ts file, is it possible to serve a static HLS playlist to embed the single ts file without segmenting it.

I am looking at playing in AVPlayer (iOS native). It is capable of playing .ts files but only if it's wrapped and served in a HLS playlist. Is there any special tags or version in need to support this usecase or is this not possible?

The goal here is to trick HLS into doing progressive download of the transport stream.

Answer (score 0):

I'm gonna big to say no, it's not possible. Even if it "worked" it's unsupported and could stop working any minute. There are many, many (many, many) free, open source, commercial, official, unofficial, etc, segmenters available, including ffmpeg. Just use one.

Comment: Thanks for confirming my thoughts, but the constraints do not allow me to do so.